# mysql workbench on 64bit Mac OSX

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

I need to insall mysql Workbench on a 64 bit Mac OSX, but there only seems to be a 32 bit at the download page: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html

Does anyone know if there is a 64 bit available?  Or is it OK to install the 32 bit version on a 64 bit Mac?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can savely install the 32-bit version on you Mac, it will run!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the 32 bit version and it will run just fine, i do it on my own Mac.

Comment: Thanks guys..I have downloaded and installed the 32bit (twice). It installs, and sort of runs, but getting really strange behaviour that is hard to explain.  Mouseovers are not under the mouse.. the ui thinks the mouse is about 100pixels below where it is.  I can't close tabs or open certain items as the mouse doesn't register as sitting over it.  Don't know for sure this is a 32 vs 64 bit issue, but something not right..

Comment: @Jason: This is a [known issue]( http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65607) that will surely be fixed in upcoming versions. Meanwhile reducing the screen resolution seems to help as explained in the link.

Comment: @Sergio Can you please explain it in more detail, so I will up vote your answer.

Comment: @VVB The bug is fixed now. There's no need to do anything other than upgrade MySQL Workbench. And, btw, I don't care for upvotes :-P